# Uniform Convergence of a Simple sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I am so stuck on this. I feel like I am making such a stupid mistake. It is to show that the sequence $\lbrace nxe^{-nx^2}\rbrace$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,\infty)$ for every $a > 0$. I know that the $f_n$ has a maximum at $x=\frac{1}{(2n)^{1/2}}$. Any help would be very appreciated at this point.

I am also wondering what the difference is when we consider $x \in (0, \infty)$. I know that the sequence does not converge uniformly on that domain, but I am wondering what makes it so different.

If anyone would be so kind as to write a proof for this, that would be much appreciated. I think I have thoroughly confused myself.

Comment: Some advice : Notice that the location of your local maximum goes to the origin in the limit. This means that there is a large enough $N$ so that the maximum will be less than $a$ for any $n>N$. Now you can show that you have a monotone decreasing function in $[a,\infty)$. This means the largest the function will ever be in the interval is its value at $x=a$. Hope that helps.

Comment: The reason your interval has to avoid being close to the origin is that the local maximum is headed there and it can be arbitrarily large.